# Vault Integration with Spring boot using APPROLE pull method

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hashicorp-vault

I'm new to the Vault. I'm trying to integrate Vault with spring boot using `APPROLE` as the authentication method.  My configuration of bootstrap.yml is as follows:

```
spring:
    application:
        name: <application-name>
    cloud:
        vault:
            host: <host-url>
            scheme : https
            port: <port>
            kv-version: 2
            namespace: <namespace-name>
            authentication: APPROLE
            app-role:
                role-id: <role-id>
                role: <role-name>
                app-role-path: <path>
```

when I'm running using this configuration. I'm getting error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'vaultTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/vault/config/VaultAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.vault.core.VaultTemplate]: Factory method 'vaultTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'vaultSessionManager' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/vault/config/VaultAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'vaultSessionManager' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientAuthentication' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/vault/config/VaultAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.vault.authentication.ClientAuthentication]: Factory method 'clientAuthentication' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Token (spring.cloud.vault.token) must not be empty
```

I'm wondering why it's asking for `TOKEN` if I used the authentication method as `APPROLE`.

Also, is it possible to use full pull mode for `APPROLE` authentication since secret-id is of dynamic nature and can't be stored in the configuration file?

Comment: What's the name of the configuration file you listed above? It should be bootstrap.yml, rather than application.yml, I believe.

Comment: Yes it's bootstrap.yml

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Need urgent Help !!!

Answer (score 0):

The sample yaml for spring cloud configuration using APPROLE authentication is described below. There are a few things that are misspelled in the config you have mentioned

```
cloud:
    vault:
      uri: https:<vault-uri>
      authentication: APPROLE
      app-role:
        roleId: <roleId>
        secretId: <secretId>
```